# Accessing object attributes in pyqt window in separate module

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a main window created in one python module. This module also contains a class definition used to create an object called my_settings.

I also have a separate module which creates a another window (which should be in a different module for various reasons). This window allows various inputs such as opening a file and storing some settings once buttons are clicked blaa blaa.

What I want to do is then amend the attributes of my_setttings. A simplified version of the code is:

**MAIN MODULE**

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi(self.some_directory + "arc_custom_main.ui", self)

        self.some_button.clicked.connect(self.open_some_widget)

    def open_some_widget(self):
        widget = widget_in_other_module(self)
        widget_in_other_module.exec_()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
my_settings=settings()
_mainWindow = MainWindow()
_mainWindow.show()
```

**SEPERATE MODULE**

```
class widget_in_other_module(QDialog):
  
    def __init__(self, parent):

        my_settings.temppath = my_settings.OutputDir

        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        my_settings.some_attribute= foo

        uic.loadUi("some.ui", self)
  
        self.pushButtonOpenMain.clicked.connect(self.openMain)

    def openMain(self):
        my_settings.some_other_attibute=bar
```

The problem I have is that I can't find a way to be able to access my_settings in the openMain method of widget_in_other_module. I'm a bit of a newbe to qt and can't for the life of me work out where I should pass my_settings. For various reasons I need all the functionality of widget_in_other_module to be outside of the main module (mostly to do with readability and future planed changes to the main module). I've tried as much as I can think of e.g. including it as a parameter in the line self.pushButtonOpenMain.clicked.connect(self.openMain,my_settings) but this doesn't seem to be allowed. Am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate settings variable in separate module and import this varable where you need it. It could be object of a class or just dictionary.

`storage.py`

```py
class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Settings")

my_settings = Settings()
```

`MainWindow.py`

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
import sys
from Widget import Widget

from storage import my_settings

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.open_some_widget()

    def open_some_widget(self):
        widget = Widget()
        widget.show()
        widget.test()
        self._widget = widget

my_settings.foo = 10

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
_mainWindow = MainWindow()
_mainWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

`Widget.py`

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

from storage import my_settings

class Widget(QWidget):

    def test(self):
        print(my_settings.foo)
```